# set different bg color for carousel items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on the carousel sample code on the Bootstrap website.
I would like to set different background colors for each item in the carousel.
I use extra css classes for each item where I set the background color. However, the only way I could get it to work is to set the important flag.

What is a better way of handling this, especially without the important flag?

Here's the html:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item second">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Second headline.</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up tomorrow</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item third">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Third headline.</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Never sign up</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here's the css:

```
.carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #777;
}

.second{
    background-color: #f00 !important;
}

.third {
    background-color: #0f0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might need to add !important see if that works worked for me a while ago but every body system different

```
<div class="item one bg1">
<div class="item second bg2">
<div class="item third bg3">

.carousel .item .bg1 {
    background: green;
}
.carousel .item .bg2 {
   background: red;
}
.carousel .item .bg3 {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #777;
}

.second{
    background-color: #f00;
}

.third {
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

Don't assign a Backgroun Color for .carousel .item because the specificity of this is bigger then the others. That's why you needed to use !important.

Check the Fiddle out -> http://jsfiddle.net/XVBqJ/1/

Comment: active class seems to have a different purpose, actually. Do you think it is a good practice to override the .active class like that?

Comment: if you named your first carousel item "active" than why not.. You could create another class aswell.